# How to use cv::Mat in python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm working on a eye pupil detection project. I found this link for eye center tracking using image gradient method provided in this link.

link- http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/

He has implemented the idea in c++ and i want to convert it into python code. Everything is going smooth until i get to this void createCornerKernel() function.

```
cv::Mat *leftCornerKernel;
cv::Mat *rightCornerKernel;

// not constant because stupid opencv type signatures
float kEyeCornerKernel[4][6] = {
  {-1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1},
  {-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 1},
  {-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, 3},
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
};

void createCornerKernels() {
  rightCornerKernel = new cv::Mat(4,6,CV_32F,kEyeCornerKernel);
  leftCornerKernel = new cv::Mat(4,6,CV_32F);
  // flip horizontally
  cv::flip(*rightCornerKernel, *leftCornerKernel, 1);
}
```

How would i convert this cv::mat(4, 6, CV_32F, kEyeCornerKernel) in python?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you not want to use OpenCV - [Python opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Comment: Python version of OpenCV uses numpy arrays instead of cv::Mat.

Comment: @Anže, i know in python we use numpy arrays instead of cv::Mat but i don't know how would i pass kEyeCornerKernel in numpy.array()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rightCornerKernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1],
                              [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
                              [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 3],
                              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: thanks man but what about this line rightCornerKernel = new cv::Mat(4,6,CV_32F,kEyeCornerKernel);?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working a bit more on this just to find the solution. As @stormzhou suggested i finally able to solve the problem.

Answering my own question, void createCornerkernels() function in python would be

```
def createCornerkernels():
    leftCornerkernel = None

    rightCornerKernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1],
                                  [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
                                  [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 3],
                                  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

    leftCornerKernel = cv2.flip(rightCornerkernel, 1)

    return leftCornerKernel, rightCornerKernel
```